# Convert NSDates from one calendar to another

Tags: ios, nsdate, nscalendar

There are lots of questions with the same title but none has answered my question. I want to be able to convert a NSString that represents Islamic calendar to a NSDate that displays that date in Gregorian calendar. This is the code that i have but it still returns the NSDate in Islamic Calendar.

```
- (NSDate*) convertToNSDateFromString : (NSString *)dateString : (NSString *)dateFormat
{
//Format the Calendar
NSDateFormatter *f = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
NSCalendar *gregorian = [[NSCalendar alloc]
                         initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
[f setCalendar:gregorian];
[f setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterLongStyle];
[f setDateFormat:dateFormat];

NSDate *date = [f dateFromString:dateString];

return date;
}
```

Comment: May be you should return an NSString? Try this if it possible.

Comment: You are confusing yourself with the date objects. They are single points in time. Since you are passing a string representing an islamic date, your formatter's calendar should be `NSCalendarIdentifierIslamic`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `NSDate` does not have a calendar. This is actually a time stamp representing a certain time. Try reading a bit about [EPOCH](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epoch_(reference_date)) to get a better understanding.

Anyway a `NSDate` can give you a duration in seconds from a reference time using `timeIntervalSince1970` this will return a number of seconds from 1.1.1970 UTC and this is actually all what the `NSDate` is. That means there are no magic tools to work on this object at all.

What you need beside this object is a calendar, a `NSCalendar` should do the trick. This calendar can help you convert the time **representation** but not the time itself. So all you can do with it is to convert a time stamp to a different representation of the date or you can get a time stamp from a certain representation of the date. Why this is so is because most of the time you can find 24 locations on earth where each of them have a different current time due to the time zone... It is not that I think you do not know this, just trying to explain why date tools are so complex and hard to use.

Comment: Ok Matic, Thanks for the reply. I get it now. Isn't this exactly what im doing with the gregorian calendar that i set in my code?

Comment: What you did is parsed a string representing a date in gregorian calendar with a given format. What you got is a time stamp (NSDate) representing that specific moment in time. So no, if the string is in Islamic you should parse as Islamic, what you will get will again be a NSDate stamp representing a certain moment in time. Then you may create a string from Gregorian calendar representing that specific moment in time.