# Creating UNNotification with non Gregorian Calendar

Tags: ios, time, calendar, usernotifications

I’m building my App to fire daily, weekly and monthly notifications in IOS swift 4. The notifications work perfectly using Gregorian calendar. However, when I change the date to Hijri calendar (Calendar(identifier: .islamicUmmAlQura) it does not wrk. It seams the UNCalendarNotificationTrigger converts any date to Gregorian calendar.
Below monthly notification code works perfectly when using Gregorian calendar:

```
func myNotification(at date: Date, withTitle title:String, andBody body:String, notificationIdentifier:String) {

let calendar = Calendar(identifier: .gregorian)
let components = calendar.dateComponents([.day,.hour, .minute], from: date)
let trigger = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger(dateMatching: components, repeats: true)
let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
content.title = title
content.body = body
content.sound = UNNotificationSound.init(named: "notificationSound.wav")
let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: notificationIdentifier, content: content, trigger: trigger)
UNUserNotificationCenter.current().removePendingNotificationRequests(withIdentifiers: [notificationIdentifier])
UNUserNotificationCenter.current().add(request) {(error) in
    if let error = error {
        print(" error: \(error)")
    }
}
```

}

The below code does not work when I covert the date to Islamic date using (Calendar(identifier: .islamicUmmAlQura) :

```
func myNotification(at date: Date, withTitle title:String, andBody body:String, notificationIdentifier:String) {

let calendar = Calendar(identifier: .islamicUmmAlQura)
let components = calendar.dateComponents([.day,.hour, .minute], from: date)
let trigger = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger(dateMatching: components, repeats: true)
let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
content.title = title
content.body = body
content.sound = UNNotificationSound.init(named: "notificationSound.wav")
let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: notificationIdentifier, content: content, trigger: trigger)
UNUserNotificationCenter.current().removePendingNotificationRequests(withIdentifiers: [notificationIdentifier])
UNUserNotificationCenter.current().add(request) {(error) in
    if let error = error {
        print(" error: \(error)")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It worked after adding the calendar type to the trigger

```
trigger = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger(calendar:calendar, dateMatching: components, repeats: true)
```

Comment: The `calendar` parameter is not available anymore. It is unnecessary because the DateComponents can contain the Calendar as demonstrated in another answer.

Answer (score 1):

Add `.calendar` to components, this will make `UNCalendarNotificationTrigger` calculate date using your calendar.

```
let date = Date()
let calendar = Calendar(identifier: .gregorian)
let components = calendar.dateComponents([.calendar, .day, .hour, .minute], from: date)
let trigger = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger(dateMatching: components, repeats: true)
```

Answer (score 0):

If the `UserNotifications` framework expects `DateComponents` interpreted in a certain calendar, then that is the calendar you must use. This doesn't mean that the underlying datetime will change, or is incorrect.

A `Date` is just a point on the timeline. How the timeline is divided up and named is a function of the calendar, but the `Date` itself doesn't know or care. The point on the timeline remains the same regardless of the description or decomposition you choose.

Cf. [Convert NSDates from one calendar to another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26100657/convert-nsdates-from-one-calendar-to-another)

Comment: Thanks. It used to work perfectly with Objective-C, It might be a bug with X-Code 9.